# Can I stretch the screen resolution for the intel 865 chipset?

Tags: linux-mint, resolution, intel-graphics, on-board-peripheral, stretch

I am using the onboard graphics chipset on my Aopen ax4sg max mainboard.
This mainboard uses the intel 865 chipset.

I am running linux mint 17 MATE. 
The highest resolution which is available is *1024x768* but I would like to have it *1280x1024* on my connected iiyama prolite 430s monitor.

I would like to know if this chipset from my aopen mainboard also can handle a higher resolution.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. Your Aopen mainboard + monitor *should* be capable of 1280x1024. But your Linux Mint OS does not offer the 1280x1024 resolution. See my answer below for what you need to know/do.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Although I could not find if my aopen mainboard could handle 1280x1024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. 1280x1024 will work. Intel 865 can even do better:

> The GMCH's analog port uses an integrated 350 MHz RAMDAC that can
>   directly drive a standard progressive scan analog monitor up to a
>   resolution of 2048x1536 pixels with 32-bit color at 75 Hz.

Source: [http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/252514.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20111210042754/http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/252514.htm)

Now to answer the rest of your question. Linux Mint (for whatever reason) sometimes doesn't offer all the different screen resolutions you could/should be able to use.

Follow the guide here to manually create the 1280x1024 resolution you need: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/877

Unfortunately you'll probably need to find the technical specifications for your monitor to get the sync and clock figures right.

Comment: great! I am going to try your suggestion.

Comment: @DutchArjo if you get stuck, check out the answer to this Ubuntu question (Mint is based on Ubuntu so it may be relevant). http://tinyurl.com/7lncn42

Comment: thank you! I have it now running 1280x1024. I do not have enough reputation to ' upvote'  your answer. But I accepted it.

Comment: I am now running into error messages after booting: no resolution was compatible. After that, the screen resolution is changed to the correct resolution. So it works, but starts with errors. (I have to auto adjust my screen after booting otherwise some part of the screen is not visible)

Comment: @DutchArjo Lol, that's *so* Linux right there.  I'm afraid I don't have an answer for that one, you might want to open a new question or seek help in the Linux Mint forums.